# opencv3.1, detectMultiScale, access violation writing

Tags: c++, opencv, detect

this is my code to detect something with opencv3.1.

but the function fp.detectMultiScale always make an error of

'예외가 throw됨: 쓰기 액세스 위반입니다. this이(가) 0x10였습니다.'

in english 'error was thrown: access violation writing. this was 0x10.'

plz help me to fix it...

i've already googled 3days...

if you need, i'm glad to add the messages from visual studio you want.

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/world.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
String fp_cascade = "C:\\hhhh\\CascadeTrainer\\cascade15\\cascade.xml";
CascadeClassifier fp;

void detect(Mat frame)
{
    vector<Rect> fps;
    fps.clear();
    Mat frame_gray;
    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray); 
    fp.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, fps, 1.1, 1 , 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
    printf("%d", fps.size());

}

void main() {
    if (fp.load(fp_cascade)) {
        printf("111111");
    }

    Mat img = imread("C:\\hhhh\\sample\\qwe.jpg");
    detect(img);
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: On which line did the error occur?

Comment: fp.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, fps, 1.1, 1 , 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

This line of my code.
then after some stack frame levels.

template<typename _Tp> inline
Rect_<_Tp>::Rect_(const Rect_<_Tp>& r)
    : x(r.x), y(r.y), width(r.width), height(r.height) {}

finally this lines of types.hpp occur exception.

r has a correct value and 'this' has a adddress of 0x00000010{x=??? y=??? width=???...}